# 3C Error Code on Samsung Dishwasher DW80K7050UG

Tags: dishwasher

I have a 2017 Samsung Dishwasher (Model Number: DW80K7050UG) that started failing with error code 3C, which refers to draining related error. The dishwasher drains perfectly at first after starting the dishwasher but then gets stuck and finally errors out with 3C error code.

I replaced the drain pump on the dishwasher to rule out the possibility of a faulty drain pump, but the 3C error persists.

Any ideas on what else I might try to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a sensor or other electronics. The Samsung website suggests restarting (which it seems you've done more than a few times) and then if the problem continues, contacting them for service. Following that logic, if it were the mechanical pump it seems like it would either work or not work, but working intermittently seems to suggest a computer/sensor/electronics issue.

Comment: Is the dishwasher full of water when the error happens?  Is the drain hose and sink drain clear and not kinked?

Comment: @GregNickoloff Thanks! Yes it does sound like sensor/computer related issue as it drains the first time fine. Do you know of any triaging I could do to identify the faulty sensor for example? Will also reach out to Samsung service

Comment: @JPhi1618 Thanks! Yes there is some residual water at the bottom of the dishwasher after it errors out. I confirmed that the drain hose is clear but blowing some air into it and confirmed some water came out the other end. Sink is also clear

Comment: I looked up a parts list, and the only sensors I could see are Turbidity (dirt sensor) and a leak sensor in the base, but it knows there is a drain issue somehow.  The turbidity sensor could double as a water sensor, but its expensive so you would want a way to test it.  Easiest thing is to check and make sure the drain pump is getting power when it should.  If the unit is supposed to be draining, and the motor doesn't run, then its a control board/relay problem most likely.

Comment: @Daddy No not specifically. Personally, my next step would be to contact the people who made it.

Answer (score -2):

See the repair at  https://www.justanswer.com/appliance/hcmq8-getting-error-code-3c-samsung-dishwasher-acts.html  Its a sensor in the drain system replaceable on the back: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZY2kvSYQLY

Comment: Link only answers become useless when the link goes bad and are frequently confused with spam. Be sure to provide context around the link and quote relevant content in case the link goes bad. See [how to answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more details.